# kubernetes rolling update for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am performing a simple rolling update for **elasticsearch** image. The command I use is

```
kubectl set image deployment master-deployment elasticsearch={private registry}/elasticsearch:{tag}
```

However, the elasticsearch always gets IOException after the rolling update.

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to read [id:60, legacy:false, file:/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/_state/global-60.st]

I have checked the directory `/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/_state/`. It has `global-10.st` file present but not `global-60.st`.

How should I make sure the image itself synchronizes well with the files present?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with statefulSet and external storage (I.e pvc - don’t store the data inside the pod. )

Comment: Yes, I do use pvc to mount data, but when I do rolling update, the data is not updated or nuked.

Comment: @JiashenCao  that’s why you need the stateful set - it makes sure the disks gets reattached to the new pod

Comment: I see. I will try that option. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain more why the elasticsearch is looking for a different `global-xx.st` file? It should always search for the same file even though the volume is not correctly reattached right? Otherwise, I feel like configuring a **StatefulSet** will not be helpful.

Comment: It’s the global state file, the number is the version - you lost the 60 version... the version 10 you have is started from the rolling upgrade ... a sort of rolling new cluster failing to recover.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done it yet. I have a lot setups kind of dependent on this deployment, so I need to change all those setups.